# Elasticsearch - Deciding number of nodes/shards based on heap usage

Tags: java, memory, elasticsearch, jvm, search-engine

We have 2 major indices and both are updated/incremented with high frequency. One of the index (product_index_v10) undergoes bulk update every midnight, updating 3-4 fields for all documents.

```
Index              Doc count Pri Rep Store.size Pri.store.size
aggregations       18708399  5   0   49.2 gb    49.2 gb

product_index_v10  5525887   5   1   144.1gb    69.8gb
```

We have faced multiple downtimes due to high heap usage, when we had 1 replica set for both indices. As a precautionary measure, aggregations' replica has been set to 0, or else 2 of the node heap constantly remains 90+.

Our cluster has 6 data only + 3 master only nodes, while each index has 5 shards. Having less number of shards compared to number of nodes is also causing shard imbalance considering cumulative shard size per node, making heap of nodes having more shards 90+.

Memory distribution for data nodes:

```
01
Store: 40.3 GB
Filter Cache: 1.5 GB
Field Data: 30.6 MB
Completion: 8.1 GB
Segments: 8.1 GB
Heap: 62-75%

02
Store: 42.3 GB
Filter Cache: 1.5 GB
Field Data: 30.8 MB
Completion: 9.1 GB
Segments: 9.1 GB
Heap: 50-75%

03
Store: 22.3 GB
Filter Cache: 1.5 GB
Field Data: 13.1 MB
Completion: 6 GB
Segments: 6 GB
Heap: 55-75%

04
Store: 36.3 GB
Filter Cache: 1.5 GB
Field Data: 26.8 MB
Completion: 8.1 GB
Segments: 8.1 GB
Heap: 60-75%

05
Store: 27.8 GB
Filter Cache: 1.5 GB
Field Data: 27.9 MB
Completion: 4.8 GB
Segments: 4.8 GB
Heap: 30-70%

06
Store: 23.7 GB
Filter Cache: 1.5 GB
Field Data: 14 MB MB
Completion: 5.5 GB
Segments: 5.5 GB
Heap: 30-70%
```

We'll be releasing new features soon, one being adding Parent-children mapping, which increases heap by 10% by filling id_cache. Besides, our product_index_v10 is predicted to increase by about 40% in 3-4 months, which will eventually increase Heap memory.

Our concerns are:

1. If node level memory components are analysed, above sections take
   more than the assigned JVM size (16 GB), which is possible since
   segment pushed only portion of its data in memory. Besides,
   **mlockall is off** currently. So how do we ensure, heap do not exceed 60-75% in general scenario ?
2. How many shards should be set per index, to be scale ready and also
   ensure that cumulative shard size per node stays equal, to avoid
   heap imbalance ?
3. Is this high heap consumption (when having a replica for each index)
   normal ? Given our use case (heavy one time indexing, average search
   queries throughout day), should we expect this much heap ?
4. We will be trying reducing memory components like completion data. How to reduce segments ?

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: Where do you have those stats numbers from? I find it odd to see Completion and Segments with same values. Something must be wrong: if your heap size is 16GB for the first node just adding up Completion and Segments and you are already over 16GB.

Comment: From the _nodes/stats API, while `heap_committed: "15.9gb"`

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Is it possible that segments are using swap memory ?

Comment: No. Provide the _nodes/stats api output in a gist, please.

Comment: @AndreiStefan [Here](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/bddc42622f00fa0293c9d7fd97e6fe39)

Comment: First of all, if you only have those two indices, I would configure them to so that each has 6 primary shards. So that the data and load is spread evenly on all nodes. Secondly, how are you doing your bulk updates? Have you tested with different bulk batch sizes? Also, if you are updating all documents, it's far better to delete the index and create a new one with the new values.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Agree with your sharding advice. Plus, our bulk update is a scheduled script sending batches of 250 docs with a sleep time of 1.25s between each batch hit. We've tried multiple variations of batch sizes and sleep time and this works properly for now. 
Also, one clarification. We do not update all the fields in each documents daily, and instead we update only 4-5 fields per doc in that index.

Comment: The dangerous part is updating **all documents**. It doesn't matter how many fields you update, but that you are updating all documents. Don't do that! Create a new index, index updated documents in this new index, then delete the old index (like `DELETE /product_index_v10`). And use [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/indices-aliases.html) to switch between the old `product_index_v10` index and the new `product_index_v10_new` index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112067/discussion-between-utkarsh-mishra-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: @Val Need more info ?

Comment: I guess you're in very good hands already with @AndreiStefan ;-)

Comment: Its a privilege to be assisted by any of you both :)