# Spring Data Elasticsearch id vs. _id

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.0.1 with Elastic version 2.2.0.

My DAO is similar to:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;    

@Document(indexName = "myIndex")
public class MyDao {
    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    <other fields, setters, getters omitted>
}
```

Saving the object to ES using a repository the `_id` metadata field gets populated correctly. The getter and setter methods for the `id` field correctly return the value of the `_id` metadata field.  But the id field within the `_source` field is null.

2 questions:
1) Why is the id field null?
2) Does it matter that the id field is null?

Comment: Are you letting ES generate its own IDs or are you providing your own IDs? i.e. are you at all calling `MyDao.setId("abcdxyz")` ?

Comment: I am letting ES generate its own IDs. Can I use auto-generation of IDs to get the ID to show up in both fields?

Comment: @wxkevin A different question, but can you share your pom. I am stuck with errors while trying to use spring-data-elasticsearch 2 :  [question-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047845/cannot-use-custom-autoconfiguration-with-spring-data-elasticsearch/37107628)

Comment: I can't copy and paste but I can tell you the dependencies and version numbers: spring-core (4.2.5.RELEASE), spring-webmvc (4.2.5.RELEASE), javax.servlet-api (3.1.0), elasticsearch (2.2.0), spring-data-elasticsearch (2.0.1.RELEASE), jcl-over-slf4j (1.7.16), logback-classic (1.1.5). If you need something else specific please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you're letting ES generate its own IDs, i.e. you're never calling `MyDao.setId("abcdxyz")` then the `_source` cannot have a value in the `id` field.

What is happening is that if you generate your own IDs and call `setId("yourid")`, then Spring Data ES will use it as the value for the `_id` of your document and also persist that value into the `_source.id` field. Which means that `_source.id` will not be null.

If you don't call `setId()`, then `_source.id` will be null and ES will generate its own ID. When you then call `getId()`, Spring Data ES will make sure to return you the value of the `_id` field and not `_source.id` since it's annotated with `@Id`

To answer your second question, it doesn't matter that the `_source.id` field is null... as long as you don't need to reference it. Spring Data ES will always populate it when mapping the JSON documents to your Java entities, even if the underlying `id` field in ES is null.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to get Elasticsearch to generate the ID and use that ID in my id field?

Comment: Yes, ES IDs are stored in the `_id` field which is different from `_source.id`(or whatever name you want to give that field). The best approach is to generate your own IDs and call `setId()`

Comment: I used @JsonIgnore in id attribute and the field was not created in ES!