# Filtering Documents with nested field nested value Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My Data demo:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "username": "demo",
  "email": "dasdasdas@dsadas",
  "number": "000111000",
  "createdDate": "2022-07-13",
  "educations": [
    {
      "name": "test01",
      "score": "5.00",
      "config": {
        "configName": "Ha Ha",
        "isVisible": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "demo02",
      "score": "4.50",
      "config": {
        "configName": "Hi Hi",
        "isVisible": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "demo03",
      "score": "4.00",
      "config": {
        "configName": "Hu Hu",
        "isVisible": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to show all data where `educatations.config.isVisible = true`

my java code that I tried is following:

```
boolQueryBuilder = boolQueryBuilder.must(
                       nestedQuery("educations.config", 
                           termQuery("educations.config.isVisible", true),
                           ScoreMode.Total));
```

But It's returning all data.

Can anyone help me out with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the demo data you provided consists of one single document, which inside of a nested array has the data you want to filter on.

By default, Elasticsearch will always return all *complete* documents that match a query. Since one of the nested fields matches your query, the complete source is returned. This is correct and intended behavior.

If you instead want *partial* hits of one document, there are several options, though none of them may yield exactly what you intend:

While you could use `_source_includes` and/or `_source_excludes` to [get partial results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/docs-get.html#get-source-filtering) from Elasticsearch, afaik you cannot do so conditionally. I.e. you could

```
GET test_index/_search?_source_excludes=educations
```

but this will remove *all* `educations` fields from the result, not based on a condition like your question entails.

A way to kind of get what you want is to use [`inner_hits` in a nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html):

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "educations.config",
      "query": {
        "match": {"educations.config.isVisible": true}
      },
      "inner_hits": {} 
    }
  }
}
```

Each `hit` will have an additional section `inner_hits` that contains only the (sub-)hits for the nested fields that meet the search condition. By default the `_source` of the returned hits inside `inner_hits` is relative to the `_nested` metadata. So in the above example only the `config` part is returned per nested hit and not the entire source of the top level document:

```
"_source" : {
  "id" : "1",
  "username" : "demo",
  "email" : "dasdasdas@dsadas",
  "number" : "000111000",
  "createdDate" : "2022-07-13",
  "educations" : [
    {
      "name" : "test01",
      "score" : "5.00",
      "config" : {
        "configName" : "Ha Ha",
        "isVisible" : true
      }
    },
    {
      "name" : "demo02",
      "score" : "4.50",
      "config" : {
        "configName" : "Hi Hi",
        "isVisible" : false
      }
    },
    {
      "name" : "demo03",
      "score" : "4.00",
      "config" : {
        "configName" : "Hu Hu",
        "isVisible" : true
      }
    }
  ]
},
"inner_hits" : {
  "educations.config" : {
    "hits" : {
      "total" : {
        "value" : 2,
        "relation" : "eq"
      },
      "max_score" : 0.4700036,
      "hits" : [
        {
          "_index" : "test_index",
          "_type" : "_doc",
          "_id" : "dQSz94EBbpRrdmjWWpzK",
          "_nested" : {
            "field" : "educations.config",
            "offset" : 0
          },
          "_score" : 0.4700036,
          "_source" : {
            "configName" : "Ha Ha",
            "isVisible" : true
          }
        },
        {
          "_index" : "test_index",
          "_type" : "_doc",
          "_id" : "dQSz94EBbpRrdmjWWpzK",
          "_nested" : {
            "field" : "educations.config",
            "offset" : 2
          },
          "_score" : 0.4700036,
          "_source" : {
            "configName" : "Hu Hu",
            "isVisible" : true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For a java solution, check the `NestedQueryBuilder` returned by `QueryBuilders.nestedQuery` in order to configure `inner_hits` there. The following SO post on [Elasticsearch inner hits in java api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32830299/14015737) may also help.

You could also combine the two (`_source_exclude` and `inner_hits`) to make your response more compact, assuming `education` is also of `nested` type:

```
GET test_index/_search?_source_excludes=educations
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "educations",
      "query": {
        "match": {"educations.config.isVisible": true}
      },
      "inner_hits": {} 
    }
  }
}
```